# Let $S$ be a subring of a commutative Noetherian ring $R$. Then $R$ is finitely generated as an $S$-module?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, finitely-generated

Let $S$ be a subring of a commutative Noetherian ring $R$. Then how can I show that $R$ is finitely generated as an $S$-module?

Comment: The paper imposes the "finitely generated" condition as a hypothesis.  It need not hold in general; consider $S=\mathbb{Z}$, $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

They assume that $R$ is finitely generated over $S$. In general this is not true. An example where this is not the case would be $R=\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $S=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I see -- thanks! I've edited the question and was wondering if this is true...

Comment: Well, you still need to assume that it is finitely generated. My counterexample is still valid, as $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is noetherian by the Hilbert basis theorem.

Comment: excluding the case (and similar ones involving polynomials rings) where $R=\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $S=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What is the precise statement, you'd like to prove?

Comment: Let's say $S$ is a subring of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $\mathbb{R}\subsetneq S$. Then can I show that  $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is finitely generated as an $S$-module?

Comment: Let $\mathbb{R} \subsetneq S \subseteq \mathbb{R}[x]$. This means, you have some polynomial $f\in S$ with degree greater equal to one. Then is $x$ algebraic over $S$ and hence $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}[x]$ is an algebraic extension. Then $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is finitely generated over $S$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39506/discussion-between-wuli-and-severin-schraven).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to show. For example, $\Bbb Q$  is a subring of the Noetherian ring $\Bbb R$ but of course $\Bbb R_\Bbb Q$ is not finitely generated.